# how do i specify an interface in dhcpd.conf?

Tags: dhcp

I have a dhcpd.conf that looks like this. How do I listen on interface enp2s0?

```
#
# DHCP Server Configuration file.
#   see /usr/share/doc/dhcp*/dhcpd.conf.example
#   see dhcpd.conf(5) man page

subnet 192.168.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    authoritative;
    range 192.168.10.10 192.168.10.100;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

On Red Hat 8 and derivatives, you now don't have to do anything, except configure your interfaces and your `dhcpd.conf` correctly:

```
[root@foo ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/dhcpd 
# WARNING: This file is NOT used anymore.

# If you are here to restrict what interfaces should dhcpd listen on,
# be aware that dhcpd listens *only* on interfaces for which it finds subnet
# declaration in dhcpd.conf. It means that explicitly enumerating interfaces
# also on command line should not be required in most cases.
...
```

If you check `/var/log/messages`, you'll see that:

```
...
No subnet declaration for eno1 (no IPv4 addresses).
** Ignoring requests on eno1.  If this is not what
  you want, please write a subnet declaration
  in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
  to which interface eno1 is attached. **
...
```

So this should Just Work (TM), but points are awarded for worrying about running a DHCP server on the wrong interface. ;)

Answer (score 2):

dhcpd man page shows:

> COMMAND LINE
>
> The  names of the network interfaces on which dhcpd should listen for
>   broadcasts may be specified on the command line.  This should be done
>   on systems where dhcpd is unable to identify non-broadcast interfaces,
>   but should not be required on other systems.  If no interface names
>   are specified on the command line dhcpd will identify all network
>   interfaces which are up, eliminating non-broadcast interfaces if
>   possible, and listen for DHCP  broadcasts on each interface.

On Debian, interfaces on which dhcpd listens must be specified in `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server` ([ref](https://wiki.debian.org/DHCP_Server#Configuration)):

```
INTERFACES="enp2s0"
```

On RedHat, it seems to be in `/etc/sysconfig/dhcpd` ([ref](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sect-configuring_a_multihomed_dhcp_server)):

```
DHCPDARGS="enp2s0";
```